# How do I stop changing desktops with the scroll wheel? (Lubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu

I saw some posts on this topic but not for the current version of lubuntu, would like to get this annoying feature dissabled.

Comment: I am on Kubuntu so this might not apply, also my system is German so the translations might not fit but I have to do: right-click > (bottom) setup Desktop > mouse. There I have options for left, middle and right button middle button has the scrolling option.

Comment: @totalynotanoob nope, setup desktop doesent even pop up when i right click, but i mean, lubuntu barrely has any setting GUIs so im not suprised.

Comment: Perhaps slightly off topic, but if you don't use the other desktops you can reduce the number of desktops to 1 in "Openbox settings > Desktop". You'll only have 1 desktop but it stops the annoying desktop switching.